# How to turn an html canvas into an image and then draw that canvas onto the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, rescale

I'm currently working on an html canvas javascript game, and it's just about finished, but I want to scale up the canvas so the whole game is bigger. I tried using something like

`var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 500);`

`ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0,0,0,360,600)`

but using this method I couldn't increase the size of the image. What is the best method for this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this, the two that i've experimented with would use 2 seperate canvases, putImageData is a little weird, and does not work well for scaling up, what i would recommend, is have a separate canvas, the size of the scaled up version, and then use ctx.drawImage to draw the first canvas on the scaled up version:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100)

var scaleX = c2.width / c.width;
var scaleY = c2.height / c.height;

ctx2.drawImage(c,0,0,c2.width,c2.height)
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The other way is to just scale up the context, then draw the image at 0,0, with no width or height specified:

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

var c2 = document.getElementById('c2');
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d')

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100)

var scaleX = c2.width / c.width;
var scaleY = c2.height / c.height;

ctx2.scale(scaleX,scaleY)
ctx2.drawImage(c,0,0)
ctx2.scale(1/scaleX,1/scaleY)
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 2px solid black
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="c2" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

One more option is to use the css scale() tag, but that messes with mouse clicks, and is really annoying so i wouldn't do that. Keep in mind, all methods that scale up the canvas (unless your scaling up coordinates and redrawing), will result in blur.

Hope this helps :D